# How do I delete dropped items in a specific area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I delete items in a specific area, because I don't want to delete everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To kill items within radius `R` from point `(X, Y, Z)`:

```
/kill @e[X,Y,Z,R,type=Item]
```

Replace `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `R` with numbers. For example, to kill all items within 20 blocks of `(50, 64, -30)`

```
/kill @e[50,64,-30,20,type=Item]
```

---

To kill items within a `DX` wide, `DY` high, `DZ` long cuboid starting at point `(X, Y, Z)` (most negative corner of the cuboid):

```
/kill @e[X,Y,Z,dx=DX,dy=DY,dz=DZ,type=Item]
```

Similar to above, replace capital `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `DX`, `DY`, and `DZ` with the values you want. For example, for a cuboid with opposite corners `(100, 64, 100)` and `(150, 70, 130)`:

```
/kill @e[100,64,100,dx=50,dy=6,dz=30,type=Item]
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found this and tried it but it didn't work, I ended up finding out a command that does work in 1.12 though

```
/kill @e[type=item,r=(number)]
```

Just replace (number) with the radius that you want and it works!